# Qt app works on desktop, but not laptop?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt-creator

I am writing an OpenGL app using Qt, and it builds and runs fine on my desktop, but when I try running the exact same code on my laptop, it builds but does not output anything? Here is my main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>
#include "GLWidget.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    GLWidget window;
    window.resize(1050,700);
    window.setFixedSize(1050, 700);
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

I do not want the user to be able to resize the window, hence the fixed size. If I set a breakpoint on the last line of main, it never reaches it on my laptop. I have stepped through the code and right after show() is called (which is just an inline function) the debugger finishes with code 0. I checked all the project build and run settings, they are the same on both machines.
My desktop has a 1920x1080 monitor, but my laptop is only 1366x768 could this have anything to do with it? Is there some sort of internal check going on under the hood in Qt that depends on my screens resolution? That is pretty much the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Maybe it's something internal in your GLWidget.h?

Comment: Your guess might be correct, @pixelpusher. There's a simple test you can do, divide the sizes you are passing by 2, and see if the new application can run on the desktop as well as on the laptop.

Comment: the only thing in my GLWidget.h is the class declaration. Seeing as the same code runs fine on my desktop, I feel like it is more of an environment issue.

Comment: I'd check DPI settings also, in case your size expressed in pixels is getting autoscaled.

Comment: @KeithThompson am using win7 on both comps

Comment: @karlphillip I tried dividing by 2, same results. works on desktop, not on laptop

Comment: @BenVoigt the DPI is set to 100% on both machines

Comment: Can you create a **GLWidget** of any size on your laptop? I think your investigation should start here.

Comment: @karlphillip when I debug on my laptop, the GLWidget constructor is called, the resize call succeeds, and the debugger exits after the show() call. This happens for any size of GLWidget.

Comment: Do you have all the Qt libraries installed on the laptop? It might be missing a dependency problem or it may be trying to use a different version of a library. Make sure your PATH environment variable points to the right libraries.

Comment: Back in the time I had seemingly similar problem with one Windows XP machine in a hospital with severe access restrictions. OpenGL Qt app wouldn't run - crash on startup. Eventually I narrowed it down to the OS OpenGL dlls. App was not allowed to use OS level OpenGL libs OR OpenGL was missing from the OS. Try using `depends` on QtOpenGl4.dll on your laptop to check if all the dlls are accessible. Also, do you recompile your app on laptop or just copy the binary from the desktop?

Comment: Check if you have the latest display drivers.

Comment: To ask a very obvious question: Did you compile Qt with OpenGL support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not want the user to be able to resize the window

May I ask why? May I presume you want the window to be a fixed size, because you want to use OpenGL to generate a image exactly this size? If so, then I must tell you, it will not work that way. OpenGL implementations will only render what will become visible on the screen (pixel ownership test). If parts of the window are not visible (and in your case this will be the case on the laptop) those pixels are simply not rendered. Reading out the framebuffer will leave those pixels undefined.

The proper way to tackle this problem is using either a *PBuffer*, or a *Frame Buffer Object (FBO)*. FBOs are easier to use, but not as widely supported on Windows (Intel graphics on Windows have rather poor FBO support). FBOs are supported by all Linux OpenGL implementations (Mesa (also does Intel), ATI/AMD and NVidia). There are numerours FBO and PBuffer tutorials in the web.